# What is data.table's equivalent of dplyr's df |> filter() |> mutate()?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Say I have this data.table:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

test <- data.table(x = 1:5)
```

---

To filter out where `x == 2` then multiply the result by 2 in dplyr I'd do:

```
test |> dplyr::filter(x == 2) |> dplyr::mutate(x = x * 2)

#>    x
#> 1: 4
```

What is the equivalent of that in data.table syntax?

---

This works:

```
test <- test[x == 2]
test[, x := x * 2]
test
#>    x
#> 1: 4
```

But I was expecting something along the lines of:

```
test <- data.table(x = 1:5)
test[x == 2, x := x * 2]
test
#>    x
#> 1: 1
#> 2: 4
#> 3: 3
#> 4: 4
#> 5: 5
```

Which doesn't do what I want.

---

This will also work:

```
test[x == 2, .(x = x * 2)]
```

But is there a way to do it without dropping the other columns?

Comment: `test[x == 2, .(x = x * 2)]` or chaining the data.table like a pipeline `test[x == 2][,x := x * 2]`

Comment: Is there a way to do that without dropping other columns in the data.table?

Comment: Does it have to be in one pair of square brackets? The second expression I gave should achieve what you want and is pretty efficient. @Mwavu

Comment: @ekoam Have you tested the expression? It just returns the original data.table

Comment: No, it returns the data.table you want. Do `res <- test[x == 2][,x := x * 2]` and see what is `res`. @Mwavu

Comment: Thanks! So the trick is to assign to an object?

Comment: Yes, but that's not really a trick. There are some deeper reasons that you should know before you start playing with the `:=` operator in data.table. Read the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/:=). @Mwavu

Comment: Have you tried `dtplyr`? It should help generating good translations.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks a lot! This has been very useful.

Comment: fyi, interactively, if you you don't want to assign to an object, here are two ways to chain: `test[x==2] %>%  .[,x:=x^2] %>% .[]` or `test[x==2][,x:=x^2][]`